# SoundCloud - get song name from url

Tags: javascript, iframe, soundcloud

Is there a way in JavaScript to get the song name from a URL?
I use an `<iframe>` tag, but I can't get the document of soundcloud and find the title of document.

HTML:

```
<span id="iframe_container"></span>
<span id="name"></span>
```

JS:

```
var video_url_new = '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/81619639&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
var link_new;


//play song
play();

function play(){
    link_new = video_url_new.replace("></iframe>", " id='i_song_name_i'></iframe>").replace("auto_play=false", "auto_play=true").replace(' width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"', '');
    document.getElementById("iframe_container").innerHTML = link_new;

    // And here's the problem:
    document.getElementById("name").innerText = document.getElementById("i_song_name_i").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText;
}
```

... and my browser returns this error:

**Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**

I know soundcloud doesn't allow to get document in frame, so I want to ask; is the website (or something like that) with the informations about the song without iframe protection?

Comment: What does a sample html iframe embed look like?  Please update your question with some markup.

Comment: @Grevling Thanks for edit! ( I can't speak english very well :} )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can get information out of the `iframe` because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which does not let you access content of `iframe`s residing on another domain.

On the other hand there is the [soundcloud api console](https://developers.soundcloud.com/console) which I've also used to get the name of a song.

That means that there is an API call for getting information about a certain song with a specific id but you will have to use a totally different approach (use the soundcloud api) to get it, instead of trying to mine it out of an iframe (which might only be possible in a hacked browser)

You can see an example `REST` request for the data [here](https://apigee.com/snapshot/soundcloud?snapId=apigee-console-snapshots-1406869200000_bd418463-28ae-4be3-a464-88c815b7ba71#content=request) and on the other tab you can see the response containing all metadata of the song.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Links to the console and apigee are no longer valid.